# Как удалить элемент из ListView, если всё держится на массиве

Tags: java, android, массивы, listview

Как удалить элемент из ListView, если всё держится на массиве?
P.S. на ArrayList не могу перейти, нужен только массив

```
String[] a = {"text","text1","text2"};

ListView l;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_del);

    l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.l);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, a);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);

    l.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SparseBooleanArray chosen = ((ListView) parent).getCheckedItemPositions();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Почему на `ArrayList` не можете перейти?

Comment: ответ прост - используйте ArrayList, в котором уже реализован метод удаления!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Длина массива это фиксированное значение и изменить его нельзя.
Возможны варианты:

1. создать новый массив, без удаленного элемента (см. [System.arraycopy](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/System.java#System.arraycopy%28java.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%2Cint%29)). И использовать этот массив в дальнейшем: подменить ссылку, создать новый адаптер, установить новый адаптер в ListView
2. Можете использовать часть кода [ArrayList.remove(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29). В этом случае в конце массива будут накапливаться null-элементы. Скорее всего ListView будет пытаться их отобразить.